# Convert bytes into readable data ble wahoo cadence sensor

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to convert the speed sensor value into a readable format.

...

Below is the data bytes obtained from the wahoo speed sensor

Output obtained using ble programmatically:
[image: Raw output]
Bytes : [2,196,0,94,7]

Channels[image: ble channels]
The above data byte[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZtF7.png) seems like a wheel rev and I'm trying to decode the last wheel event time.

.....

The output obtained using nrfconnect app Ima[image]ge:

Crank rev:3
Last crank event time:37932ms

Set of observed values:[image: readings]

I found that byte[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZtF7.png) represents the crank rev count value, it's difficult for me to find the **Last crank event time** from bytes output

Comment: I you have a small byte array then please post the values also in hexadecimal notation.

Comment: byte[2] has value 0 by the way. byte[0] has value 1.

Comment: cant find anything in here: https://api.wahoofitness.com/android/api/1.4.0.2/com/wahoofitness/connector/capabilities/WheelRevs.Data.html

Comment: 37932 ? How did you calculate that?

Comment: Wheel rev:3 Last wheel event time:37932ms this is the output from the nrfconnect app.I don't know how they extracted the exact value

Comment: info updated please check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BLE Cycling Speed and Cadence Service - Crank Timing Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624472/ble-cycling-speed-and-cadence-service-crank-timing-data)

Comment: its does not helps me @Risto

Comment: I found that byte[1] represents the crank rev count value, it's difficult for me to find the Last crank event time from bytes output

Comment: and what do you don't understand? Your sensor delivers  "Crank Revolution Data" and the first value is the "Cumulative Crank Revolutions" and the second is the "Last Crank Event Time" with a resolution of 1/1024s. Both values are uint16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [GATT Specification Supplement 5](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/gatt-specification-supplement-5/) it describes how to intepret the bytes:

[image]

[image]

Looking at the data:  `[2, 4, 0, 94, 23]` the `2` is in the `flag` position and represents `Crank Revolution Data Present`.

The `4, 0` are `Cumulative Crank Revolutions`. As the data is in `little endian` the value is `4`.
The `94, 23` are `Last Crank Event Time` which is this case is a timestamp at `5982` (5.84 seconds)

Comment: to calculate timestamp 94+23/1024=. is this correct???

Comment: i can't understand Last Crank Event time pls help. @ukBaz

Comment: Apologies, my answer needed to be divided by 1024. So `94, 23` is in little endian format so is `5982` as an integer which needs to be divided by `1024` to get the timestamp in seconds. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm still trying to understand little-endian format 94,23 to 5923, If possible could you please explain @ukBaz

Comment: Example of converting list of bytes to integers https://stackoverflow.com/a/63573566/7721752. More informaton on endianess https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-endianness-big-endian-vs-little-endian/

Comment: Sorry to bother, what you are telling here is that the bluetooth ble standard already define standards about how to design speed /caddnce sensors ?

Comment: @pippo1980, yes, there are some adopted services and characteristics that are documented by the Bluetooth SIG. A manufacturer can follow that for interoperability or they can do their own thing. Full list at: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/

Comment: `I'm still trying to understand little-endian format 94,23 to 5923,` You will only understand if you display both values in hexadecimal notation.